# xamarin APK successful but it doesn't even open

Tags: xamarin, build, apk

The APK is created once I tried to install the APK on the mobile devices it installs but it doesn't open in the android 6.0 and in the android 5.1 doesnt even install.

The Devices OS are 
Android 5.1 -API 22 
Android 6.0 - API 23

MY test device are

Android 5.1 using xamarin live player 
Android Emulator 6.0

both of them works fine but when I have created the APK it doesn't even work.

This is the build information

[image]

I have also adjusted the target framework to 8.0 and 8.1 but still it doesn't work.

Output 
    [`Build Output`](http://%60https://pastebin.com/bCy3FZnF%60)

Comment: Are you using a Release configuration and performing an Archive/Publish_AdHoc to create the APK?

Comment: Yes i do using the release config and archive/publish_adhoc 

I am following an old tutorial since 2016 to early 2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be two .APK files in your bin folder.

1. projectname.Droid.Apk
2. projectname.Droid-Signed.Apk

Use Signed one to run it on Device.

Comment: Thank you mate i will try it and give feed back.